# flush rewrite rules after plugin update?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, automatic-updates

I am working on a plugin that registers custom new endpoints in every update and we need to Flush Rewrite Rules after every update of the plugin.

Flushing Rewrite Rules are easy after activation of the plugin and there is a lot of tutorials out there about this

But in the case of Flushing Rewrite Rules after Update 
I can't find any solution

Comment: you can save the plugin version in an option and when the version change, you flush the cache.

Comment: thank you
your comment was the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your answer above was close but is should be

```
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'wp_answ_355114' );
```

not

```
do_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'wp_answ_355114' );
```

noting that this is only the case when a plugin is updated view WP plugin updates.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified this but you could try the [upgrader_process_complete](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete/) hook.
[More information on that hook.](https://pluginrepublic.com/wordpress-plugin-update-hook-upgrader_process_complete/)

like follows

```
function wp_answ_355114() {

flush_rewrite_rules(); 

}

do_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'wp_answ_355114' );
```